# Array_agg containing distinct structs

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm attempting to create an array with distinct struct as values for a column, something like so

> select array_agg(distinct struct(field_a, field_b)) as c FROM tables ...

is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(field_a, field_b)) c 
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT field_a, field_b
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
)
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, though, that's not really what I'm after.

Comment: sorry to hear that this is not what you were looking. you might want to post new question with more specifics and with more details on what is use case and expectations