# DISTINCT in ARRAY OF STRUCT in Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am looking for the way to make array of struct has unique value. Here the example table.

[image: -------------------------------------]

Into this
[image]

I only found similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53602131/array-agg-containing-distinct-structs), but it I think it only caters 1 nested repeated column. But what if the tables contains 2 or more nested repeated columns? In this case, column `country`, and `product`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> But what if the tables contains 2 or more nested repeated columns?

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT * REPLACE(
  (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(id, total_visit_count))
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT id, total_visit_count FROM UNNEST(country) c
  )) AS country,
  (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(name, total_visit_count))
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT name, total_visit_count FROM UNNEST(product) c
  )) AS product
)
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

If you have more columns to dedup - you can just simply repeat above for each such column

OR, you can use SQL UDF to encapsulate dedup logic in one place as in below example

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION dedup(val ANY TYPE) AS ((
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(t)
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM UNNEST(val) v) t
));
SELECT * REPLACE(
  dedup(country) AS country,
  dedup(product) AS product
)
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Obviously, the latter would be my choice to go with :o)